# fatal error mysql queries codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Trying to build a menu in a view. Giving me fatal errors/undefined query functions. The database is connected to via the load->database() in the construct of the controller. Not that familiar with codeigniter db queries but I assumed regular mysqli would work fine. Here's the code:

```
<div class="at_mainMenu gradient02">
  <ul class="sf-menu" id="example">
  <?php
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE priority=0");
    foreach ($query ->result_array() as $row) {
      echo "<li class='current'><a href='".$row['link']."'>".$row['text']."</a>";
      $id = $row['menuId'];
      $children = $this->db->query ("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE parentId=$id ORDER BY priority DESC");
        foreach ($children->result_array() as $row) {
          echo "<ul><li><a href='".$row['link']."'>".$row['text']."</a>";
            $id2 = $row['menuId'];
            $grandchildren = $this->db->query ("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE parentId=$id2 ORDER BY priority DESC");
            foreach ($grandchildren->result_array() as $row) {
              echo "<ul><li><a href='".$row['link']."'>".$row['text']."</a></li></ul>";
            }
          echo "</li></ul>"; 
        }
      echo "</li>";
    }
  ?>
  </ul>
```

Comment: select what from menu ?

Comment: I don't think you know how to use CodeIgniter correctly - please [consult the documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/examples.html)

Comment: Please look into `join`s in SQL or just general SQL syntax :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not query without specifying the columns. You may want to use `*` for all columns or `col1, col2`

```
SELECT [column list] FROM [table_name]
```

Comment: added a SELECT * to it, unfortunately same issue.

Comment: second and third query ?

Answer (score 0):

you can call mysql throught your view. this is bad if you still impose... but if you want to learn, i can help you to understand how to create a simple way to work with model, view and control.

Step 1. Controller:

first create a controller in controller folder with name my_controller.php,
and put this code:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

        class My_controller extends CI_Controller {

            public function __construct() 
            {
                parent::__construct(); 
                date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Bangkok');
                $this->load->model(array('my_model'));
                $this->load->database();
                $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
            }

            public function index()
            {
                $result_query = $this->my_model->GetMenu();

                $data['list_menu'] = '';

                foreach ($result_query as $key => $value) {
                    $data['list_menu'] .= '<li>';
                    foreach ($value as $index => $item) {
                        $data['list_menu'] .= '[' . $index . '] = ' . $item . ', '; 
                    }
                    $data['list_menu'] .= '</li>';
                }

                $this->load->view('my_view', $data);

            }

        }

    /* End of file My_controller.php */
    /* Location: ./application/controllers/My_controller.php */
```

Step 2 Create your View:
create a file with name my_view.php in view folder inside application folder, and puth this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My View</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Simple List Menu!</h1>

    <ul>
        <?php echo $list_menu; ?>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Step 3. create your model:

create a file with name my_model.php inside model folder
and put this code:

```
<?php
class My_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->database();
    }

    function GetMenu()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('Menu'); // where menu is your table name

        return $query->result_array();
    }

}
```

Cheerss..
you must reading this ...
it will guide you to the light. so your not blind anymore.
[CI Documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter)
note: application folder is in root folder. you will se it. if dont then is not code ignither.
hope this will help.